# Site synchronization with aliases

Tags: drush

I configured the site aliases for the development, and staging sites. I have the `<DRUPAL_HOME>/sites/default/aliases.drushrc.php` aliases file with this content:

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'root' => '/home/drupaltest',
  'uri' => 'localhost',
  'path-aliases' => array('%dump' => '/home/drupaltest/dump.sql')
);

$aliases['stage'] = array(
  'root' => '/home/drupaltest',
  'uri' => 'naftalin',
);


$aliases['all-scratch'] = array(
  'site-list' => array('@dev', '@stage'),
);
```

`drush @dev status` outputs:

> hubidubi@couscous:/home/drupaltest$ drush @dev status
>        Drupal version         :  6.25
>        Site URI               :  localhost
>        Database driver        :  mysqli
>        Database hostname      :  localhost
>        Database username      :  root
>        Database name          :  drupaltest
>        Database               :  Connected
>        Drupal bootstrap       :  Successful
>        Drupal user            :  Anonymous
>        Default theme          :  garland
>        Administration theme   :  garland
>        PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
>        Drush version          :  4.4
>        Drush configuration    :
>        Drush alias files      :  /home/drupaltest/sites/default/aliases.drushrc.php 
>        Drupal root            :  /home/drupaltest
>        Site path              :  sites/default
>        File directory path    :  sites/default/files

Then I tried to run `drush rsync @dev @stage` command to sync dev site to stage and I get:

> Could not evaluate source path @dev.

I can't figure out the problem; I think the alias file is correct.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drush rsync command does not bootstrap your site, so it cannot find your alias files.  Move your alias files to a global location (e.g. $HOME/.drush).

Also, since @dev and @stage are multisites with the same document root, it does not make any sense to rsync from one to the other, because they share the same files.  You might want to `drush rsync @stage:%files @dev:%files`.

Comment: The path is the same, but host is different. There's no way to hold the site and the aliases together?

Comment: If @stage is on a different machine, then you will need to add 'remote-host' and 'remote-user' items to the site alias record.  Otherwise, Drush will assume that the site is on the local machine.  Add these items, set up an ssh key pair with the remote machine, move your aliases file to $HOME/.drush, and you should be in business.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't see this information anywhere else and was pretty confused--you can't use a an aliases.drushrc.php file in the sites/default folder like a lot of guides suggest.